# Get the value of return within class

Tags: php

Goodday. The question is, how can I get the return value and pass to my other php file?

**myclass.php file**

```
class myClass{
function banner(){
    $sql = "Select * From tblBanner";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $banner = $row;
return $banner;
}

}
```

**my index.php file**

```
include 'myclass.php';
$banner = new myclass;
$ban = $banner->banner;
echo $ban;
```

This is what im trying to do. Im a newbie so spare with me. Thank you.

Comment: change `$ban = $banner->banner;` to `$ban = $banner->banner();`

Comment: besides, avoid `mysql_*`, try `mysqli_*` since the former is deprecated

Comment: Well, youre trying to access a method like a property. This CANT work. As already mentioned, you need to use `banner()` instead of `banner`. Additionally, creating new instances of classes is case sensitive, so you need `new myClass` instead of `new myclass`.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS! Im working on this all day. -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I already wrote in the comments, `$banner->banner` would be a property of the class "myClass". But you want to get a method, so you have to use `$banner->banner()`.

myclass.php file

```
class myClass{
    function banner(){
        $sql = "Select * From tblBanner";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $banner = $row;
        return $banner;
    }
}
```

my index.php file

```
include 'myclass.php';
$banner = new myclass;
$ban = $banner->banner();

// example for array:

foreach($ban as $banner) { 
    echo $banner;
}
// example for string:
echo $ban;
```

An example for $banner->banner:

myclass.php file

```
class myClass{

    public $banner = 'Banner Property';

    function banner(){
        $sql = "Select * From tblBanner";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $banner = $row;
        return $banner;
    }
}
```

my index.php file

```
include 'myclass.php';
$banner = new myclass;
$ban = $banner->banner;
echo $ban;
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir but what am I gonna do if the return value is an array?

Comment: Well, then you get an array back and you have to loop through it with a foreach, i will write you an example into my answer

Comment: Okay sir i got the idea. But how about when I fetch it in an array? e.g $ban['data'],$ban[data2]. How can I get those values?

Comment: Don't understand..^^ sorry